# firebase.User in firebase version 9

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm writing a new app with React, typescript and firebase.
I'm working on the AuthContext and in a tutorial I found I see these lines:

```
import firebase from "firebase/app";

const [user, setUser] = useState<firebase.User | null>(null);
```

But the import
import firebase from "firebase/app";
does not exist on firebase 9 and I can't find the equivalent of firebase.User

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3):

I am not familiar with React and AuthContext but maybe this can help. This is how `User` type can be imported in typescript and in Firebase v9:

```
import { User } from "firebase/auth";
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, if you get

```
TS1484: 'User' is a type and must be imported using a type-only import when 'verbatimModuleSyntax' is enabled.
```

then you should use this format

```
import { type User } from 'firebase/auth'
```